# Properly handling required properties with inheritance in SpringDoc / Swagger

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, springdoc

In a Spring project, we're using springdoc / swagger to generate our API OpenAPI description.

We're currently facing a problem with required properties in children classes.

We've got a parent class:

```java
@Value
@NonFinal
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({ Type(value = ChildADto.class, name = "A"), Type(value = ChildBDto.class, name = "B") })
public abstract class ParentDto {
   @NotNull
   protected String parentProp;
   // ...
}
```

And two children classes (basically the same, so here's only one of them):

```java
@Value
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class ChildADto extends ParentDto
{
    @NotNull
    private String childAProp;
    // ...
}
```

The JSON generated to describe the API has an error for the children classes:

```json
...
"ChildADto": {
  "required": ["childAProp", "parentProp"],
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ParentDro"
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "childAProp": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
...
```

instead of:

```json
"ChildADto": {
  "required": ["parentProp"],
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ParentDto"
    },
    {
      "required": ["childAProp"],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "childAProp": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The property childAProp should be tagged as required in the `allOf` part, not directly in the `ChildADto` part. When reading this JSON with orval to generate the typescript API client, childAProp is then seen as optional.

Is there a way to better describe the java DTOs, in order to get the required attribute put at the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it's not the better solution, there are probably some caveats, but I found a way to fix the generated Schema by Swagger, using the `OpenApiCustomizer`.

The idea is to walk through the Schemas and re-apply required properties to sub-schemas found in `allOf` if any.

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration
{
    // imports are from swagger and apache-commons, nothing exotic
    
    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public OpenApiCustomizer customizeOpenApi()
    {
        return (openApi) -> {
            for (Schema schema : openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().values())
            {
                fixRequiredPropertiesIn(null, schema);
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private void fixRequiredPropertiesIn(Schema parentSchema, Schema schema)
    {
        Collection<String> stillRequired = EMPTY_COLLECTION;
        if (parentSchema != null)
        {
            Collection<String> parentProperties = defaultIfNull(parentSchema.getProperties(), new HashedMap<>()).keySet();
            Collection<String> parentRequired = defaultIfNull(parentSchema.getRequired(), EMPTY_COLLECTION);
            stillRequired = removeAll(parentRequired, parentProperties);
        }
        // could be a $ref, nothing to fix then
        if (!StringUtils.equals(schema.getType(), "object"))
        {
            return;
        }
        Collection<String> properties = defaultIfNull(schema.getProperties(), new HashedMap<>()).keySet();
        Collection<String> required = defaultIfNull(schema.getRequired(), EMPTY_COLLECTION);
        Collection<String> maybeRequiredProperties = removeAll(properties, required);
        Collection<String> toAddRequired = intersection(stillRequired, maybeRequiredProperties);
        // add missing 'required'
        for (String toAdd : toAddRequired)
        {
            schema.addRequiredItem(toAdd);
        }
        // recursion
        if (schema.getAllOf() != null)
        {
            for (Object subSchema : schema.getAllOf())
            {
                fixRequiredPropertiesIn(schema, (Schema) subSchema);
            }
        }
    }
}
```